# Cannot understand why I am getting a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, multithreading, nullreferenceexception

I have a block of code that is reading from a queue, processing one item (in its own thread), and then repeating until the queue is empty.

```
public ActionResult GetOrdersAsync() {

        int count = 0;
        SyncDM sync = _common.StartSync();

        while (sync != null && sync.SyncId != 0) {

            int customerId;
            bool result = int.TryParse(sync.Payload, out customerId);
            if (result) {
                Task.Run(() => GetOrders(sync.SyncId, customerId));
            }

            count++;
            //Process the next Sync
            sync = _common.StartSync();

        }

        return Json(new JsonModel {
            Message = "Started " + count + " instances of GetOrders",
            Success = count > 0
        });

    }
```

StartSync() either removes an item from the queue, or returns null if the queue is empty.
GetOrders() processes the object.

The problem is that sometimes the code raises a NullReferenceException on this line
    Task.Run(() => GetOrders(sync.SyncId, customerId));

In the debugger, Sync is `null` (reason for exception), but customerId has a value. This tells me sync had a value on the previous line. This is confusing me, I'm thinking it has something to do with Task.Run and threading but I don't understand how a locally scoped variable is spontaneously changing its value.

Comment: If your sync = _common.StartSync() invalidates your sync object before and of the GetOrders() finishes, it makes sense why it would do this. Can you make GetOrders and GetOrdersAsync() as actual async methods, and then await GetOrders? It will then wait before attempting to process the next Sync.

Answer (score 6):

You're updating the reference of `sync` before your task gets a chance to operate on it. Note that tasks don't necessarily start immediately. In some cases, your task may start after the following is executed further down:

```
sync = _common.StartSync();
```

Now your reference to `sync` is potentially null, and when your task goes to access `sync.SyncId`, you get a null reference exception.

Change your code to the following:

```
if (result) {
    var syncId = sync.SyncId;
    Task.Run(() => GetOrders(syncId, customerId));
}
```

This works because we just want to pass in the Id. What if you wanted to pass in the object itself? You'd need to create a new variable which will *not* be modified outside of the closure:

```
if (result) {
    var capturedSync = sync;
    //Assuming GetOrders now takes a `Sync`
    Task.Run(() => GetOrders(capturedSync, customerId));
}
```

Comment: For your last example, that's a shallow copy. Changing sync will also change capturedSync. He would need to do a deep copy, in which I would just keep to your first example.

Comment: @Dispersia "Changing sync will also change capturedSync" ...and you're absolutely sure about that?

Comment: @spender yes? that's what a shallow copy does. Try it for yourself, create an object, assign it (this will do it by reference), then change the new object, and see the original change as well.

Comment: @Dispersia That is incorrect. Changing a member within `sync` would also 'change' `capturedSync`. However, we're interested in *assignments to sync*, not the internals of `sync` changing. A deep copy is not required in this situation - and I'd wager to say, most situations

Comment: @Rob we don't know what StartSync does. If it clears its state and then tries an assignment, like most business objects will do, it will clear SyncId before it nullifies it, removing the SyncId data from capturedSync, which will then not be the value you're expecting. That is a volatile solution.